# How to convert PCM audio to Opus using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am having a WAV file with PCM format and I would like to know if there is a way to convert it to Opus format with OGG container, using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to take the standard Opus encoder and compile it to JavaScript with [emscripten](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/index.html). Here is a project that already has that set up: [opus.js-sample](https://github.com/kazuki/opus.js-sample)

Comment: I ran into an issue while setting up that project: https://github.com/kazuki/opus.js-sample/issues/2

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what [opusenc.js](https://github.com/Rillke/opusenc.js) is for: Converting entire in-memory files into Ogg-Opus. Give it a try on its [**demo page**](https://blog.rillke.com/opusenc.js/).